# git fatal:No tags can describe <sha1 number>

Tags: git, tags, commit

I am using tags by applying them to nightly builds.  Then later, I want to use the output of `describe --tags --match <latest tag>` to tell me how far from the nightly build my images are.  This is for QA testing.

I just ran into an error in a clone that is older than the current tag.  I ran git fetch --tags, so I see the tag in git tag output, but when I run `git describe --tags --match <tagname>`, I get `fatal: No tags can describe <head sha1 version number>`.  I cannot do a git pull to update the workspace at this point.  Why does this happen and is there a workaround? Thanks very much

Comment: FYI: It is possible to run into this situation where you've previously tagged commit SHA(s), then rewritten history and force pushed, resulting in previous tags now falling outside of the history of the branch. Be warned, writing history and ignoring previous tagged commits can be a bad idea.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It happens because you only fetch the tag, not the commit history of the tag. `git describe` uses this history, which is why it has an error.

The only workaround is to fetch repo's history containing the tag you're interested in, using `git fetch <remote-name>`.

Comment: $ git fetch
remote: Counting objects: 10, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
remote: Total 6 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (6/6), done.
From thoroughbred:flt/root
   facbb9f..045ec3a  main       -> origin/main
   facbb9f..045ec3a  main_int   -> origin/main_int
$ git describe --tags --match MAIN_INT-74
fatal: No tags can describe '2eb966ad1c2a9b78be2b09e8e329f54a695a0f86'.
Try --always, or create some tags.

Comment: Yes I meant `git fetch remote`. Can you see the tag in gitk or any other viewing mean? Are you sure that the tag is a parent of your current HEAD?

Comment: I just ran git pull and updated the workspace, and the describe command still fails. Is this really expected?

Comment: maybe you're in detached HEAD? What happens if you run describe without --match?

Comment: Yes, I can see the tag when I run git tag.

Comment: not in a detached head.  The pull failed in a clone of a different branch, so you can ignore that comment.  But the one where I ran fetch is the same branch.  Once I ran a pull the describe works.  So, I guess I understand that even though I can list the tag, if I cannot see the commit it references in git log, I won't be able to describe it.  right?

Comment: So, this is why I am confused about tags.  It seems to me that git tag should not list new tags that point to content that I don't have in my clone.

Comment: also, if I am on a different branch and I merge in from the branch that was tagged, should I be able to run describe on the tag?

Comment: I answered my own question.  I tried the merge and yes, I can run describe on the tag successfully now.

Comment: Great to hear you solved it, it's better if you write it a an answer to your question. Cheers

Comment: In refence to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802145/how-to-convert-a-git-shallow-clone-to-a-full-clone

You can use `git fetch --depth=2147483647`, which is sufficient within Azure DevOps Pipeline as well.

Answer (score 26):

I just ran into this error with `git version 2.8.3` and command `git describe --abbrev=0`.

The problem was that while the tag existed in the origin and my local repository was up to date, the tag did not have a commit message.

The error was resolved after I re-tagged the commit with a tag message:

```
git tag v1.1.1 -m 'some message'
```

Comment: The [`git describe` command has a `--tags` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe#Documentation/git-describe.txt---tags) which you can enable: "Instead of using only the annotated tags, use any tag found in refs/tags namespace. This option enables matching a lightweight (non-annotated) tag." This way you don't need to change your tags.

Comment: This did it for me.

Answer (score 23):

Another explanation can be that the repository was cloned with a `depth=xyz` setting (which [Travis does by default](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#git-clone-depth)). In that case, the history might be cut off before the most current tag.

Technically, cloning with `depth=xyz` creates a shallow clone with entries in `.git/shallow` that describe where to cut off history. When `git describe` then walks the history it might get to that cut-off point and stops searching for a tag. That even happens if you fetched tags manually after the initial shallow clone with `git fetch --tags`.

If this is the problem, you need to `unshallow` the repository (or create a full (enough) clone in the first place). See [How to convert a Git shallow clone to a full clone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802145/how-to-convert-a-git-shallow-clone-to-a-full-clone) to solve the problem.

Comment: Also the case with [ReadTheDocs #5031](https://github.com/rtfd/readthedocs.org/issues/5031)

Comment: I had this exact problem inside a jenkins pipeline. Even after disabling shallow clone, the project wouldn't build anymore (due to git describe returning garbage). Deleting .git\shallow resolved my issue, thanks!

Comment: This is also an issue with Azure Pipelines after Sept 2022, where depth is defaulted to 1, meaning there's a good chance the tag you expect to reference hasn't been fetched https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/steps-checkout?view=azure-pipelines#shallow-fetch

Answer (score 1):

I actually ran into this error when I have created a git tag based on git reference.

It seems that the git reference was not "in master" and this cause some problems.

So the fix was to find the proper commit reference in master and recreate the tag.

Answer (score 1):

There might be 2 reasons for this.

1. The `fetch-depth: 0` is missing while using `actions/checkout` since it requires the history upto the previous tag commit which might miss if you are doing shallow fetch.
2. You are running it on a non-main branch which doesn't have the changes since the last tag is created. Do a `git pull` and push those changes to the remote and see if it is working.

Comment: Extra big thank you for this. #1 was the issue. I tried using just `fetch-tags: true` but that wasn't enough in `actions/checkout`. It needs the full depth in order to get the previous tag and the `git diff` between that and the current commit. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked after using `git pull` instead of `git fetch`.

Enhancing on the solutions already provided: My git tag already had a tag message and `git fetch <remote-name>` didn't help in my case as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue with using below tag while doing git checkout.
fetch-depth: '0'

Comment: Always put the full commands as answers and keep it on a new line. Also surround your command with  backticks ` character to display it as different from normal text.