# How to convert a Git shallow clone to a full clone?

Tags: git, clone

Follow-up of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209999/using-git-to-get-just-the-latest-revision) so-question: if I have a shallow clone, how to fetch all older commits to make it a full clone?

Comment: Related: [Increase depth of shallow clone without fetching other branches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56539456/5353461)

Answer (score 239, accepted):

**EDIT:** `git fetch --unshallow` now is an option (thanks Jack O'Connor).

You can run `git fetch --depth=2147483647`

From the [docs on shallow](https://git-scm.com/docs/shallow):

> The special depth 2147483647 (or 0x7fffffff, the largest positive number a signed 32-bit integer can contain) means infinite depth.

Comment: Now that `git fetch --unshallow` exists (as in @sdram's answer), this answer is no longer the best one.

Comment: @sdram's answer did not work for me (git version 2.1.1), but this answer did.

Comment: Neither answer worked for me.  Both commands succeeded in fetching all the missing commits, but when I try to push new commits, I get an error about the server not knowing about 'shallow' refs

Comment: `git fetch --depth=2147483647` is the largest possible depth to provide to the command.

Comment: I used `git fetch --unshallow`, but it still does not show all the branches.

Comment: @Sid, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11623862/git-fetch-doesnt-fetch-all-branches fixed that for me.

Comment: Tip: on an unstable internet connection, we can incrementally `git fetch --depth=1000` then again `git fetch --depth=10000` and so on.

Comment: Use of `git fetch --depth=2147483647`  is sufficient within Azure DevOps Pipeline.

Answer (score 909):

The below command *(git version 1.8.3)* will convert the shallow clone to regular one

```
git fetch --unshallow
```

Then, to get access to all the branches on origin (thanks @Peter in the comments)

```
git config remote.origin.fetch "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*"
git fetch origin
```

Comment: This doesn't undo the --single-branch side effect.  To do that, edit .git/config and change  fetch = +refs/heads/BRANCHNAME:refs/remotes/origin/BRANCHNAME  to  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

Comment: This doesn't create local branches tracking the remote branches, so you still need to checkout -b BRNAME origin/BRNAME to get that set up.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714159/how-do-i-undo-a-single-branch-clone:  `git config remote.origin.fetch "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*";`  `git fetch origin`  from an answer there should be the same as editting .git/config by hand

Comment: This only works if the repo is marked as shallow. I can't remember how, but there are situations where you can end up with an incomplete repo without having explicitly done a shallow clone. @svick's https://stackoverflow.com/a/6802238/260122 is the answer that works every time.

Comment: `git fetch --unshallow --update-head-ok origin '+refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*'` worked for me

Comment: @gzaripov's one-liner **did not** work for me. It resulted in a local snapshot of remote branches that could not be configured with tracking. The three-lines given in this answer, however, do work.

Comment: This is the only solution that @Peter_Cordes posted, that worked for me

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/27393574/475821: `git remote set-branches origin '*'` does similar thing

Comment: @gzaripov under what circumstances is using the porcelain `--update-head-ok` useful?

Comment: `fatal: --unshallow on a complete repository does not make sense` If 799 people agree, something must be wrong at my end. I've yet to determine what.

Comment: Note: this option is available to `git pull`, as well, i.e., `git pull --unshallow`.

Answer (score 32):

I needed to deepen a repo only down to a particular commit.

After reading `man git-fetch`, I found out that one cannot specify a commit, but can specify a date:

```
git fetch --shallow-since=15/11/2012
```

For those who need incremental deepening, another `man` quote:

> ```
> --deepen=<depth>
> ```
>
> Similar to --depth, except it specifies the number of 
>   commits from the current shallow boundary instead of from the tip
>   of each remote branch history.

Answer (score 17):

Two ways to achieve Shallow Clone to Deep Clone. :

1. Used the following steps to download the branch: (This downloads the shallow copy of the branch and then converts it into a Full Clone i.e bring complete branch and its history).

   a. git clone -b branch http://git.repository/customSP01.git --depth 1

This does a shallow clone (with the depth-option) only fetches only one single branch (at your requested depth).

```
b. cd customSP01
c. git fetch --depth=100
d. get fetch --depth=500
....
e. git fetch --unshallow
```

//The above command will convert the shallow clone to regular one.
However, this doesn’t bring all the branches:

Then, to get access to all the branches.

```
f. git remote set-branches origin '*'
```

[This Step can also be done manually by editing following line in .git/config.

fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master

to (replace master with *):

fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
]

```
g. git fetch -v
```

This converts the Shallow Clone into Deep Clone with all the History and Branch details.

---

2. You can avoid steps f and g, if you use the below instead of command present in step a. to do the shallow clone:

   git clone -b branch --no-single-branch http://git.repository/customSP01.git --depth 1

Comment: I only needed step F. I did `git clone --depth=1 <url>`, but then `git fetch --unshallow` did not fix it, nor did `git fetch --all`: remote branch list still just had master & HEAD. Step F fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
git fetch --update-shallow
```

Comment: --update-shallow doesnt work if shallow clone is performed with depth value.

Answer (score 1):

None of the above messages did the trick. I'm trying to work with git tags starting from a shallow clone.

First I tried

```
git fetch --update-shallow
```

which kind of worked half-way through.
Yet, no tags available!

```
git fetch --depth=1000000
```

This last command really fetched the tags and I could finally execute

```
git checkout -b master-v1.1.0 tags/v1.1.0
```

and be done with it.

HTH

Comment: What's the downvote for? Please explain so I can improve upon this. Thank you.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think it might be because 'git checkout -b' is used to create a new local branch. So, I don't think it does what might be expected in the context of your answer.

Answer (score -2):

Configurations that  helped with the error is
(In GitLab)
For each project :

1. On the top bar, select Main menu > Projects and find your project.
2. On the left sidebar, select Settings > CI/CD. Expand General
   pipelines.
3. Under Git strategy, choose git fetch, under Git shallow
   clone, enter a value, 1000, the maximum value for GIT_DEPTH Read More - [https://gitlab.yourcompany.com/help/ci/pipelines/settings#limit-the-number-of-changes-fetched-during-clone{}](https://gitlab.yourcompany.com/help/ci/pipelines/settings#limit-the-number-of-changes-fetched-during-clone%7B%7D)

In the .gitlab-ci-yml (this should be done before any command that calls GitVersion.exe)

```
  before_script:
    - git fetch --prune --tags --unshallow
```