# protocol error: expected old/new/ref, got 'shallow deeb...'

Tags: git

I am editing a git repository that was cloned using `--depth 1` (shallow clone).

I want to push my changes (commits) but I get this error:

```
$ git push
Counting objects: 14, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.
Writing objects: 100% (8/8), 56.88 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 8 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)
fatal: protocol error: expected old/new/ref, got 'shallow deeb2171db739fd366...'
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

How can I solve this?

Running `git --version` I get this:

```
$ git --version
git version 1.9.rc1
```

Comment: Pushes from shallow clones was added in Git 1.9, which you obviously run on the client, but what about the server? It looks like the pushing-shallow-clone feature required changes to the Git protocol and that your server doesn't recognize what the client is sending.

Comment: @MagnusBäck Can I do something to solve this if my repo is hosted on Bitbucket?

Comment: Assuming I was right about the problem being that the server is too old, no. You'd have to wait for them to upgrade to support the new protocol.

Comment: Well, unless you don't want to copy your work into a non-shallow repository as described in one of the answers.

Comment: @MagnusBäck Yep, the second solution is shorter and easier in my case.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
git fetch --unshallow
```

Also see: [how to unshallow your repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17937889/1420197)