# How to fetch all git history after I clone the repo with `--depth 1`?

Tags: git

There is a big repo with thousands of commits. When I clone it, I just want to see the latest code, and don't wait for too long, so I run:

```
git clone git://..../... --depth 1
```

But later, I want to see all the history commits, but I don't know how to fetch all the histories.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no way to go from this repo to the full version - you will most likely need to clone the entire repo, including the latest revision, into a fresh copy in order to have the full history. I'm not 100% sure that this is the case, however, so I will leave it to somebody with more knowledge in this area to provide a more definitive answer for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert shallow clone to full clone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802145/convert-shallow-clone-to-full-clone)

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Use `git pull --unshallow` and it will download the entire commit history.

Comment: or use 'git fetch --unshallow'

Comment: I saw this when I attempted that command:
$ git pull --unshallow
fatal: --unshallow on a complete repository does not make sense

Answer (score 22):

Alternatively, you can also run `git fetch --depth=1000000`.

Comment: In a few years, this won't work if pulling the Linux kernel. :)

Comment: Maybe. but if you, like me, have trouble pulling the entire source because you use an old laptop which runs out of memory, then this is a solution that would work. With patience.