deploying affected with nx mono repo using bitbucket pipeline based on tag
I am using bitbucket pipelines and NX for a mono repo.
I am trying to use build and deploy affected using our tag based deployment, but the problem is I need to point point to a branch:
nx affected --target build --base=origin/master~1 and when I use a tag, it is a detached head and I am getting an error in pipelines:
Cloning into '/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build'...
+ git reset --hard 820b28002540f6bb4fde2a8ecd740be8929a5332
HEAD is now at 820b280 update version
..
...
..
> nx affected --target build --base=origin/master~1
fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/master~1': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.

Does anyone know how to get affected to work using version tagging for deployments?

If i understand correctly, it's comparing it to chances in a different branch? To allow that you need to fetch the git history as bitbucket drops the history prior to that commit

I guess the base is master~1, and the tag is detached, is not part of a branch. Would I do a command to get git history before I run the nx affected command?

I do branch comparison in my scripts and I run git fetch -q origin "+refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master" to get master's history

okay, that git fetch seems to work for my tag based deployment. Thanks.

@randommm actually build:affected is not always triggered correctly, especially when I have commit 1 and commit 2, and commit 2 is tagged and triggers a deploy. It compares commit 2 to master, but they are both master branches. But the work done in commit 1 is not considered in the build:affected. Do I need to use a release branch instead that is ahead of Master to be able to do a proper compare? Because that is not very workable. I don't know how NX would know what is currently build and deployed in Bitbucket, there is no history of that.

Try it with full history fetch to see if it works https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29270058

By default, BitBucket pipeline set the git history to only include the pushed commit. You can fetch the history by running git fetch in your step. This will probably not be saved for later steps, have not tested.
For you to be able to compare to your master branch, you can run git fetch -q origin "+refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master" to get the git history you need to be able to do the comparison. Replace master with other branch names if needed.

do you think build:affected can actually work on tag based deployments? Because the tag is done on the last commit and compares against master~1 which is the same as the last commit in this case. And it doesn't discover the Diff between tagged commit v0.2.10 and the last deployed tagged commit v0.2.9. Between those tags there may be many changes/commits that are not picked up

I am not good enough with git to resolve this, so I am pondering if I should go to a release branch strategy, so I can do a proper compare between master and the release branch and use affected correctly.
