# Find the number of commits in a Git repo when cloning with --depth=1

Tags: git

To find the number of commits on a git branch you can do:

```
$ git rev-list --count HEAD
920
```

However, if you initially clone with `--depth=1`, that doesn't work:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/ndmitchell/hoogle.git --depth=1
$ cd hoogle
$ git rev-list --count HEAD
1
```

Is there any way to get the speed and reduced network traffic of a `--depth=1` clone, but then also get the count of the number of commits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any way to get the speed and reduced network traffic of a --depth=1 clone, but then also get the count of the number of commits?

I'm pretty sure you can't.

As you know, `--depth=1` only retrieves the most recently pushed commit.  That means when you clone with a depth of 1 you get 1 commit and only that single commit, with no history at all attached to it.

As far as your local repository is concerned, there is no history, just this 1 commit.

As is also mentioned in [the docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone)

> **--depth**
>
> Create a shallow clone **with a history truncated to the specified number of revisions**.

What I also find interesting that even if you'd check the origin

```
$ git rev-list --count origin/master
$ git log origin/master
```

they'd both only show 1 commit, too.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be appropriate for all situations, but in certain use cases you may be able to convert your shallow clone to a full clone with (assuming Git 1.8.3+) as per [How to convert a Git shallow clone to a full clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802145/how-to-convert-a-git-shallow-clone-to-a-full-clone):

```
git fetch --unshallow
```

This will allow you to get the correct count as normal.