# git diff gives ambigious argument error

Tags: git, git-diff

I recently moved from SVN to git, and trying to learn my way around git.
I need to find the files that have changed between 2 branches of my repository. I use the following command to that:

```
git diff branch_2..branch_1
```

I get the follwing error:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'branch_2..branch_1': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

git branch gives the following o/p:

```
git branch -a
* branch_1
master/origin
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
remotes/origin/branch_2
remotes/origin/branch_1
```

Comment: This might be a silly question, but if you do a `git branch -a` are your branches in that list?

Comment: Can you paste what those two branches are listed as in your list?

Comment: git branch -a <br/>
* branch_1<br/>
master/origin<br/>
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master<br/>
remotes/origin/branch_2<br/>
remotes/origin/branch_1<br/>

Comment: You should place this in your original post just so it is easier to keep the full context.

Comment: done.. thanks for your help

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you are simply doing:

```
git diff branch2..branch1
```

This will not work, as listed in your git branch list, your 'remotes' are specified as "origin". What this actually means is that you have those branches on your remote, but they aren't actually checked out locally.

So you have two options here. Try these, and let me know how it goes.

Based on the branch list provided:

Diff using origin/

```
git diff origin/branch2..branch1
```

If you want to checkout these branches locally to perform your diff and maybe work on them on your workstation. Furthermore, supporting the diff in this format:

```
git diff branch2..branch1
```

What you need to do is actually checkout those branches to set them as local branches from your remote. Simply do this:

```
git checkout branch2
```

Then you can do

```
git diff branch2..branch1
```

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes you got a [**shallow git repo**](https://www.perforce.com/blog/git-beyond-basics-using-shallow-clones), created using

```
git clone --depth 1 <repo-url>
```

Trying to `git diff` fails w/ a `fatal: ambiguous argument error`:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument [...]: unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

You then need to make your refs locally available. Convert a shallow git repo to a full (unshallow) repo from a shallow one, see [git deep fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17937889) and [git unshallow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6802238).

Then it should be able to `git diff` branches:

```
git diff branch1
```

Aforementioned example compares `branch1` to the active working branch.

HTH

Comment: yes and I also came into this in Gitlab Pipline Settings. If Git fetch depth is set to a number,if will not fetch all branchs,commits,or so on.