# Moving subfolder from one git repo to another preserving history

Tags: git, clone

I have the typical problem of splitting up one large repo into smaller ones, so I searched and came across this: http://gbayer.com/development/moving-files-from-one-git-repository-to-another-preserving-history/

```
git clone <git repository A url>
cd <git repository A directory>
git remote rm origin
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter <directory 1> -- --all
mkdir <directory 1>
mv * <directory 1>
git add .
git commit
```

It would have worked for me, except that my clone is a shallow one. Since the repo is large, I had to clone with depth 0.
Now, what are my options?
Should I:

- Clone the repo at its full depth in the first step (OR)
- Not detach the remote in Step 3 and fetch all after filtering subdirectories (OR)
- Do anything else?

Answer (score 1):

Even without cloning again, you can [convert your current repo from shallow to "unshallow"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17937889/6309)

```
git fetch --unshallow
```

Then, you can proceed with your `git filter-branch`