# git fetch works but checkout branch doesn't work

Tags: git

I'm trying to `checkout` a branch that I've just fetched from my `upstream` remote repo but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$ git fetch upstream
Fetching upstream
From github.com:group/repo
* [new branch]      feature-branch -> upstream/feature-branch

$ git checkout feature-branch
error: pathspec 'feature-branch' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The branch is likely present in more than one remote. (You can confirm this with `git branch --list --remotes '*/feature-branch'`.) `git checkout` only creates branches like that if they’re unambiguous. From `git-checkout(1)`:

> If `<branch>` is not found but there does exist a tracking branch in exactly one remote (call it `<remote>`) with a matching name, treat as equivalent to
>
> ```
> $ git checkout -b <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>
> ```

So you’ll need to do that instead:

```
git checkout -b feature-branch --track upstream/feature-branch
```

Answer (score 4):

This post solved it for me.  I had forgotten that I had done a shallow clone of the repo. [How to convert a Git shallow clone to a full clone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802145/how-to-convert-a-git-shallow-clone-to-a-full-clone)

The below command *(git version 1.8.3)* will convert the shallow clone to regular one

```
git fetch --unshallow
```

Then, to get access to all the branches on origin (thanks @Peter in the comments)

```
git config remote.origin.fetch "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*"
git fetch origin
```

Comment: Thanks. I was going crazy about what could it be and seeing your answer made me remember I also had a shallow clone only :)

Comment: Thanks to you a lot! I had a shallow repo, then unshallowed it a few weeks ago, but I didn't know about the second-last command

Answer (score 2):

You're wanting git to understand the "shortcut" checkout notation, but it seems to find it inapplicable.  Perhaps do multiple remotes have branches named `feature_branch`?

Well, anyway, `git checkout -b feature-branch -track upstream/feature-branch` ought to work

Answer (score -1):

There are some automations that can happen when you ask to checkout a local branch that doesn't exist (create it from some remote branch, for example), but this won't fail for you: `git checkout upstream/feature-branch`. The only thing is that no local branch is being created.

Answer (score -1):

When you run `git checkout feature-branch` git try to remove all unsaved changes in file named `feature-branch`. For `checkout` your branch use `-b` option like this `git checkout -b feature-branch`.

Comment: This checkouts out a NEW branch of that name base on whatever the current checked out branch is.  This will not checkout the remote branch.