# how to use git "--unshallow" with a "--single-branch" clone?

Tags: git, shell, shallow-clone

I first shallow-cloned a repo with depth=1.

```
cd $folder_path
git init
git remote add $my_remote $url_to_repo
git fetch $my_remote $my_branch --depth=1
git reset --hard $my_remote/$my_branch
cd -
```

I then tried to unshallow the local clone by running twice this

```
if [[ ! -z "$(git rev-parse --is-shallow-repository)" ]]; then
    echo "STILL SHALLOW"
    git fetch $my_remote $my_branch --unshallow 
fi
```

I got "STILL SHALLOW" twice, and step by step still the same...

```
$ git rev-parse --is-shallow-repository
--is-shallow-repository
$ git fetch $my_remote $my_branch --unshallow 
remote: Counting objects: 16, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (12/12), done.
remote: Total 16 (delta 8), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (16/16), done.
From ssh://my_git_url.git
 * branch              my_branch -> FETCH_HEAD
$ git rev-parse --is-shallow-repository
--is-shallow-repository
```

So what am I doing wrong?
how to use `--unshallow` ?

Comment: read the first comment of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17937889/313421) answer.

Comment: still the same error message ```fatal: --unshallow on a complete repository does not make sense```

Comment: Your bash script has problem. Run command in terminal. Your clone is not shallow anymore.

Comment: when running this line it does not work ```git fetch $my_remote --unshallow
``` (i have a different remote name than origin): ```fatal: --unshallow on a complete repository does not make sense``` but ```git rev-parse --is-shallow-repository``` returns ```--is-shallow-repository```. However ```git fetch $my_remote --depth=100000``` does fetch my files but does not remove the "shallow" attribute of the clone

Comment: fatal error is a good thing in your case. It means clone is not shallow anymore.

Comment: it is not true, if I run ```rev-parse --is-shallow-repository``` again it still returns  ```--is-shallow-repository```

Comment: Your git version doesn't have such an option for `rev-parse`. Run `git rev-parse --repo-is-not-shallow-anymore`

Comment: true! it returns anything!!!

Comment: ```if [ -f $(git rev-parse --git-dir)/shallow ]; then```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git rev-parse --is-shallow-repository` is supposed to return `true` or `false` so using `if [[ ! -z "$(git rev-parse --is-shallow-repository)" ]]` always is treated as `TRUE` because even `false` (returned by command) is not an empty string.

It seems your version of `git` doesn't support `rev-parse --is-shallow-repository` sub-command and it turns out in that case any flag would be returned as output:

> $ git rev-parse --repo-is-not-shallow-anymore
>
> $ --repo-is-not-shallow-anymore

Because of following error your repo is not shallow and no further action is required:

> fatal: --unshallow on a complete repository does not make sense

Comment: Note: `--is-shallow-repository` was added to `git rev-parse` in Git version 2.15.  The OP must have a previous Git version.