# git clone via SSH takes forever to complete

Tags: git, github, ssh, git-clone

I was attempting to clone a repo with `git clone git@github.com:someorg/my-repo.git`, but the process takes forever to complete after indicating `Cloning into 'my-repo' ...`. I tried :

1. Generating a key with `ssh-keygen -t rsa`
2. Adding the public key located in `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to my GitHub account
3. Setting up an ssh-agent with `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"` and adding my key with `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`
4. Cloning the repo

Comment: Unless someone is deliberately slowing ssh traffic and speeding up other traffic, it won't matter what protocol you use to clone: you just have a big repository and/or a tiny straw you're using to suck in the copy.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you would benefit from doing a *shallow* clone:

for example:

```
git clone --depth 10 https://github.com/torvalds/linux.git
```

from the `git` man page:

```
--depth <depth>
  Create a shallow clone with a history truncated to the specified number of commits...
...
...
```

This won't give you the full git history of the repo but is likely to satisfy your needs. For a start it will give you the latest version of the repo.

Since adding the `--depth` flag to your `clone` command reduces the amount of data being downloaded, you should see a reduction in the time it takes to run a clone.

The decrease in time to clone will vary with the size and history of this particular repo. You can later download the rest of the history using:

```
git fetch --unshallow
```

See [How to convert a Git shallow clone to a full clone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802145/how-to-convert-a-git-shallow-clone-to-a-full-clone) for more details on this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however after investigation the problem was not caused by the size of the repo to clone but only by a temporary ssh connection issue. Restarting my machine has restored the connection.