# Fetching Tags in Google Cloud Builder

Tags: google-container-registry, google-compute-engine

In the newly created google container builder I am unable to fetch git tags during a build.  During the build process the default cloning does not seem to fetch git tags.  I added a custom build process which calls `git fetch --tags` but this results in the error:

`Fetching origin
git: 'credential-gcloud.sh' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://source.developers.google.com': No such device or address`

```
# cloudbuild.yaml
#!/bin/bash

openssl aes-256-cbc -k "$ENC_TOKEN" -in gcr_env_vars.sh.enc -out gcr_env_vars.sh -
source gcr_env_vars.sh
env
git config --global url.https://${CI_USER_TOKEN}@github.com/.insteadOf git@github.com:

pushd vendor
git submodule update --init --recursive
popd

docker build -t gcr.io/project-compute/continuous-deploy/project-ui:$COMMIT_SHA -f /workspace/installer/docker/ui/Dockerfile .
docker build -t gcr.io/project-compute/continuous-deploy/project-auth:$COMMIT_SHA -f /workspace/installer/docker/auth/Dockerfile .
```

Comment: Also, I can't find information on how the buidlers clone the git repo

Comment: It's difficult to answer your question without knowing the details of the "custom build process" that you added. Would you mind disclosing your build steps?

Comment: @DavidBendory, I updated the question with the build steps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me, as the first build step:

```
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/git
  args: [fetch, --depth=100]
```

Comment: I think this is working for you because you are using the git image, correct?  I'm using `gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker`

Comment: Why not use the git image for that step?

Comment: Oh!  I guess I could use that!  Not sure why that didn't occur to me.  Still, do you know why gcr builders don't fetch tags?

Comment: I had found they did fetch tags actually. But I do have an additional issue, posted here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/issues/43

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, you want all tags to be available in the Git repo, not just to trigger on tag changes?  In the latter, the triggering tag should be available IIUC.

I'll defer to someone on the Container Builder team for a more detailed explanation, but that error tells me that they used gcloud to clone the Google Cloud Source Repository (GCSR), which configures a Git credential helper named as such.  They likely did this in another container before invoking yours, or on the host.  Since gcloud and/or the gcloud credential helper aren't available in your container, you can't authenticate properly with GCSR.

You can learn a bit more about the credential helper [here](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/quickstart#add_the_cloud_source_repository_as_a_remote).

Comment: Correct, I am triggering off a branch and I want all tags to be available in the  builders container.  I'm relying on the tag to travel all the way up to a UI page to inform which version/tag I'm running

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that fetching everything (similar to TravisCI) up to some depth isn't the default

Comment: Is this happening in a build trigger or in a manually submitted build?

Comment: This is happening in a build trigger

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by doing the following: 1) create github api access account. 2) ensure that I'm using annotated git tags 3) git pull more history from the repo (--depth=200).  It looks like the builders only fetch the last commit.

3) was informed by this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6445255/2258766

Comment: So IIUC, you've got a build trigger, and one of the build steps in the cloudbuild.yaml executed when that trigger fires does a "git pull"? Or in other words, you need to pull additional source in addition to the repo that is pulled automatically by the triggered build?

Comment: Yes, but I think some of this is the result of how the clone is originally done.   My guess/understanding of the container builder's clone is that it does a limited fetching.  Specifically, it only fetches the first commit.   Which means things like `git describe --tags --dirty --always` don't work because we need a bit more history.  My versioning system relies on https://github.com/warner/python-versioneer which calls the previous `git describe...`.  So now I *need* to pull extra info to fully display tag info.