# Why might git describe always return `fatal: No tags can describe SHA1` after I converted a svn repo to a git repo?

Tags: git, svn, version-control

I am trying to convert a svn repo to a git repo. I therefore followed the second (most upvoted) answer of a previous [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79165/how-do-i-migrate-an-svn-repository-with-history-to-a-new-git-repository). I only diverged by converting svn tags to git tags and created annotated, not lightweight tags, like so:

```
git checkout -b tag_v1 remotes/tags/v1
git checkout master
git tag -a v1 tag_v1 -m "release"
git branch -D tag_v1
```

After I converted the repo, I tried to describe the git tags, as follows:

```
git describe
```

However, I only receive the following error message in return:

```
fatal: No tags can describe <SHA>
```

In addition, when I try to look at the ancestry-path from a commit related to a tag to the current HEAD as,

```
git rev-list --ancestry-path <SHA RELATED TO TAG>..<SHA RELATED TO HEAD>
```

I receive an empty response. In accordance to the accepted answer from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445148/git-fatalno-tags-can-describe-sha1-number), I made sure to fetch all remote branches. In response to the second (most upvoted answer) I also made sure that each tag is associated with a commit message. `Git show`for a particular tag reveals:

```
tag A
Tagger: foo
Date:   bar

release

commit d1c276a83a4e21dc26e019905db9a237e1366013 (tag: A)
Author: baz
Date:   bazbaz

    Created a tag for version 2.8.0
```

Does somebody know why `git describe` always return the error message? I am grateful for any hints or suggestions!

Comment: Note that a tag for the *latest* version (the last commit on the Git branch that resulted from conversion of the SVN trunk) can *only* describe the *latest* version, not any earlier versions. But if you have tags for older versions, e.g., for the very first SVN commit converted to a Git commit, those tags should be able to describe any later Git commit. So I'm not sure why you are getting this error. If you use `git tag -l` to list all tags, what tags show up for what versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have figured out the answer for this question after some long trial and error. The code to create tags when migrating a svn repo to a git repo instructs creating branches for each tag, like so

```sh
git checkout -b tag_v1 remotes/tags/v1
git checkout master
git tag -a v1 tag_v1 -m "release"
git branch -D tag_v1
```

These branches are effectively never merged into the master branch again and seem to be "orphaned" to me. I think `git describe` thus does not find a path between them.